# Fill a datagrid with EF6 and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-6

I think I pretty much have had every page there is about this subject, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly display data in a WPF datagrid. I'm still learning the ropes, but I believe everything should work, yet it doesn't. I already have a SQL Server database up and running with actual data in it, the datagrid still shows up empty however. Is there something I overlooked?

This is datagridview.xaml

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="DatagridC" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Schools}"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="SchoolID" Binding="{Binding SchoolID}" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="School" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And this is datagridview.xaml.cs (Based on an earlier question about this topic) (I know this would be smart to do with INotifyPropertyChanged, still schooling myself on what that is, but my main goal right now is to show the data)

```
    private ObservableCollection<School> schools;

    public ObservableCollection<School> Schools
    {
        get { return schools; }
        set
        {
            schools = value;
        }
    }
```

And the school class

```
public class School
{
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

}

I've tried multiple things already, sometimes I get a warning popup that no datacontext has been found, but I'm not understanding in what way that is neccesary and this time.
I'm betting I'm making rookie mistakes, but could someone point me to a right direction?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you present that creates context instance. That should be done *somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

I think as per your warning your database context is not available. you can troubleshoot this in the following steps.
Check your DB connectivity

- Check the context if it is able to open the database
- Check the query generated by your EF
- execute the query got from the above steps in SSMS
- if all these steps are passing then check your data adapter
- if the data adapter is ok then the data grid should populate
- if still there is any issue update your code for DB context and data adapter so we can look where it is failing

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` or any of its parent elements. You could for example set the `DataContext` in the constructor of `datagridview.xaml.cs`:

```
public datagridview()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

The other option is to specify the source of the binding in the XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DatagridC" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Schools, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
```

The above markup snippet assumes that the class where the `Schools` property is defined is the parent *window* of the `DataGrid`, i.e. that datagridview.xaml.cs is a `Window`. If it's a `UserControl`, you should change the `AncestorType` to `UserControl`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I went with the method underneath, changed ancestortype to usercontrol (because it's indeed a usercontrol) but stumbled upon a new error. "Member not found in datacontext usercontrol" underneath the {Binding Schools} part. Am I supposed to define the member somewhere else as well?

Comment: Where is the `Schools` property that you are trying to bind to actually defined? And where are you seeing that error message?

Comment: And how do you initialize `Schools`?

Comment: School itself is a class (and a table in the MSSQL Database) . I was under the assumption that ObservableCollection in datagridview.xaml.cs was enough to use as a binding. It's not an error I'm seeing, sorry. More of a tooltip when I hover my mouse above Itemsource="{Binding School}(etc.) letting me know that no such member exists in the datacontext, I can still run the app. I am also able to add data (trough mainwindowview.xaml) to the database (and School), so it shouldnt be a connection problem

Comment: How do you add objects to your `ObservableCollection<School>` property that you are trying to bind to...? It doesn't populate itself.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? There really isnt much to find about populating an observableCollection based on a MSSQL database

Comment: Yes, it is. It's like populating any other collection. Your question is unclear.